# Запуск Cygwin из python приложения и последующее выполнение команд

Tags: python, cygwin

У меня установлена программа Cygwin (UNIX-подобная среда и интерфейс командной строки для Microsoft Windows). Мне необходимо из моего python приложения скомпилировать некий исходный код под Linux. Т.е. грубо говоря в обычной жизни я делаю следующее. Запускаю Cywgin и помощью вот такого bat-файла:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

Появляется командная строка bash и я пишу вот такую команду:

```
cd ~/project1 && make
```

Ну и выполняю её. Но теперь, мне нужно это сделать из моего Python приложения, например, для прототипа при нажатии какой-то кнопки. Я так понимаю, что нужно создать в python приложение процесс и далее уже запускать необходимую мне команду или нет? Нужно видимо использовать модуль subprocces. Как это сделать правильно?

Я вот пробовал:

```
p = subprocess.Popen( "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c", shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
```

Comment: Так этот вариант у Вас работает и если нет, то что пишет ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант:
p = subprocess.Popen( ["C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe", "--login", "-c"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
@rem Это пакетный файл make.cmd
@echo off

@rem Переходим в папку проекта
cd /D ...\project1

@rem Выполняем make.exe
C:\cygwin\bin\make.exe
```

и запускаем в Питоне

```
p = subprocess.Popen( "...\make.cmd", ... )
```